# GeoJson styling Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, ngx-leaflet

Hi I have a problem with Asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet geojson interpretation.

My geojson is automatically generated with color and opacity corresponding to the map information. Each geojson is a FeatureCollection with multiple Polygons differently styled.

I've tried different options, I've found to set style of the Polygons, but non of them seems to work.

Example geoJson:

```
{  
   "type":"FeatureCollection",
   "features":[  
      {  
         "geometry":{  
            "type":"Polygon",
            "coordinates":[  
               [...]
            ]
         },
         "type":"Feature",
         "properties":{  
            "style":{  
               "color":"#ff0000",
               "weight":0,
               "opacity":0.2
            }
         }
      }, ... ]}
```

I've been trying multiple options that seems to work for people. Also there is nothing on styling inside geojson in the ngx-leaflet docs.

How should I set the styling above to make ngx-leaflet display proper color, stroke and opacity?

Answer (score 4):

ngx-leaflet doesn't do anything to manipulate the layers you add to the map. So, it's up to you to provide the style options when you create the features.

E.g.,

```
let geoJson = {...};
let options = { "color": "#ff7800", "weight": 5, "opacity": 0.65 };
L.geoJSON(geoJson, options).addTo(map);
```

This example was taken from here: http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/